# How can I use "Find" to search for different things in different Safari windows?

Tags: safari, big-sur

I have two Safari windows open, and I would like to search for different text within each window. For example I want to find "Foo" on one page and "Bar" on the other. Each time I change between the windows it updates the Find field to be synchronized between the windows.

Furthermore this search is synchronized between apps. Is there some way to disable this?

I looked at all of the com.apple.xxxx.plist files, but I don't see any setting that is obviously relevant.

Comment: Find uses the kill-ring [the 'spare' copy/paste buffer]. I don't think there's any way around that [but this just as a comment in case someone smarter than me knows a way].